# React js vs database

Tags: reactjs, database, e-commerce

Hello I was wandering what is better for better user experience.
I am currently building an E-commerce react training website.In which I gave the user the ability to control the items displayed depending on the prices , the brands and the items category.
Right now I fetch **all** items from the database and by user modifications the loop for displaying the items happens on the react side.
The question is : **Is it better to fetch all data once or should the user modify the displaying criteria I should only fetch items meeting the criteria ?**

I am thinking if I fetch maybe 10,000 items **Which way will be faster?** going throw them on the database side or on the React app side

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends of the architecture and your goals/requirements.
But regular way to load that data which actually need.
It especially important for weak devices (old computers and mobile). 10.000 items is quite a lot.
If user will change criterias, you will load new required data (regular cases - filtering, pagination and etc).